# variable undefined in sub function

Tags: php

The following script returns an 'undefined variable (plaatsholder) error' on the whereSlug($plaatshouder) part. Without result I've tried defining it as a global variable and by passing it as function($plaatshouder). Any clue?

```
 public function index($plaatshouder) 
{  
    $collectie = Cache::tags('plaats')->remember($plaatshouder, 40320, function()
    {
      return Plaats::select(['plaats', 'id', 'wikplaats'])->whereSlug($plaatshouder)->first();
    });
}
```

Comment: `function() use ($plaatshouder)` add this to your callback

Comment: works great! Thanks a lot!